# Generate OpenAPI for Kotlin maps

Tags: kotlin, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using OpenAPI Generator with my Kotlin API to generate code which my frontend API is generated from. This works fine, except maps are not handled like I expect.

The class

```
@Serializable
class FieldSection(
  val id: String,
  val testFields: Map<String, String>
) {
  companion object {
    val bodyLens = createBodyLens(serializer())
    val example = FieldSection(
      id = "section_id",
      testFields = mapOf("test" to "test_val")
    )
  }
}
```

results in the generated code

```
data class FieldSection (

    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: kotlin.String,

    @Json(name = "testFields")
    val testFields: kotlin.collections.Map<kotlin.String, FieldSectionTestFieldsValue>

)
```

and

```
data class FieldSectionTestFieldsValue (

    @Json(name = "test")
    val test: kotlin.String? = null

)
```

What I expect is instead

```
data class FieldSection (

    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: kotlin.String,

    @Json(name = "testFields")
    val testFields: kotlin.collections.Map<kotlin.String, kotlin.String>

)
```

I have tried with different kinds of maps, with and without polymorphism, but it seems like the values in the map is replaced by a key value pair instead of just the value in all cases.

Is this a common problem when generating an Open API? Are there any configuration options that could be tried?